# What's the equivalent of ghci's type directive in OCaml?

Tags: haskell, types, ocaml

In ghci, you can find out the type of any expression using the [type directive](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Determining_the_type_of_an_expression#Type_of_expressions).

For example, if I want to find out the type of `\ f g h -> g (h f)`, I can use the directive in the ghci interpreter like this:

```
Prelude> :t \ f g h -> g (h f)
\ f g h -> g (h f) :: t2 -> (t1 -> t) -> (t2 -> t1) -> t
```

Is there an equivalent of this for OCaml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get type information in interactive Ocaml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291326/how-to-get-type-information-in-interactive-ocaml)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may find the [utop](https://github.com/diml/utop) toplevel useful for this.  It's an enhanced version of the standard OCaml toplevel, but with:

- more sensible defaults for interactive use (short-paths enabled)
- automatic evaluation of some top-level monads, such as Lwt or Async I/O (so typing in a int Deferred.t or int Lwt.t will return the int at the toplevel)
- interactive history and module completion and all that editor goodness.

There are two ways to find the type of something.  For a value, just enter the expression into the toplevel:

```
$ utop
# let x = 1 ;;
val x : int = 1
# x ;;
- : int = 1
```

This works for values, but not for type definitions.  utop (1.7+) also has a `#typeof` directive which can print this out for you, though.

```
$ utop
# #typeof Unix.sockaddr
type Unix.sockaddr = ADDR_UNIX of string | ADDR_INET of Unix.inet_addr * int
# #typeof ref
type 'a Pervasives.ref = { mutable contents : 'a; }
```

(the last one shows you that the `ref` reference type is just syntactic sugar for a field with a single mutable `contents` field).

Another common trick to quickly dump a module definition is to alias it to a new module.

```
$ utop
# module L = List ;;
module L : sig
  val hd : 'a list -> 'a
  val tl : 'a list -> 'a list
  val nth : 'a list -> int -> 'a
  <etc>
```

You can install utop quickly via `opam install utop`.  We recommend this in Real World OCaml as the preferred interactive editor for newcomers, instead of the vanilla OCaml toplevel.

Comment: @JasonYeo note that usages 1 and 3 above are not specific to `utop`.

Comment: Awesome! `#typeof` is just what I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I find `#typeof` to be an odd name for the functionality shown. You are not getting the type of a type, just printing the definition of the type. I'd prefer `#showdef`.

Comment: The module aliasing trick isn't working for me. Its just printing `module L = Core.Std.List` instead of the module signature. I'm using utop 1.15 with Ocaml version 4.02

Answer (score 5):

Just type the function into the OCaml interpreter, and its type is automatically displayed

```
# fun f g h -> g (h f);;
- : 'a -> ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'c = <fun>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get an expression's type without doing any evaluation of that expression?

Comment: @DanielWagner Put it in a file and type `ocamlc -i`. There is another way yet that involves `ocamlc -annot`.