# What does the following line of OCaml do: type reply = (string * string list * string, error_t) result;;?

Tags: types, syntax, ocaml

```
type reply = (string * string list * string, error_t) result;;
```

I am a newcomer to OCaml, and I was trying to read through some of the Core library when I came across the above code. I can't quite figure out what it does. It seems to create a tuple of `string * string list * string`, inside of another tuple with `error_t`. I don't quite understand what the `result` modifier at the end does.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14291326/124319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` isn't a modifier, but a type that requires two type variables. Its [definition](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/result.mli#L25) is, slightly simplified:

```
type ('a, 'e) result =
  | Ok of 'a
  | Error of 'e
```

So the first type variable specifies the type of the argument to the `Ok` constructor, and the second specifies the type of the argument to the `Error` constructor.

It might seem backwards to you to have the arguments come before the type they're applied to, but doing it this way has some benefits. Firstly, `int list` reads better than `list int`, and secondly, you can write `int list list` instead of `list (list int)` as you would if you decided to follow the syntax of normal function application.

You probably also notice that there's a difference between the syntax for *tuple types* and *tuple values*. `result` takes a *tuple value* containing two *types*, the first type in this case being a tuple.

I hope that clears it up for you.